# Someone is using a bitcoin account to blackmail me

Tags: security, fraud

Someone using a bitcoin account is trying to blackmail me. The account number is 1Mtsd3wXgkJnApaNpqaSSWLC6gCLBBxuaGG.
I still have the email they sent me. I can also provide that email if needed, or I can provide full detail. 
I wasn't sure where to email or how to report this, can you direct me to the right place?

Comment: The answer by @RedGrittyBrick is correct and the Bitcoin address is not really traceable, however, an email certainly might be.

Answer (score 5):

Blackmail should be reported to your local police.

This is a question and answer website where ordinary people like you and I share helpful information on a voluntary basis. We don't run bitcoin (no one does).

The number is not an account number, it is a bitcoin address. Those are not really traceable to any specific person, computer or place. People like the FBI may be able to eventually track down criminals using bitcoin on a large scale but we can't.