# my account haked and black mailer give me add of bitcoin

Tags: transactions

I dont know who is that blackmailaer who send me a mail,,, copy below,,,

Sent: Monday, March 25, 2019 8:09 AM
To: lubby786
Subject: alqadar : lubby786

I am aware lubby786 is one of your passwords. Lets get directly to the point. Not a single person has compensated me to investigate you. You don't know me and you are most likely wondering why you are getting this e-mail? 
wykyobnj alqadar lubby786 mrwvabxy alqadar lubby786 auxddu alqadar lubby786 zapesujzz alqadar lubby786 wkkuwify alqadar lubby786 npsaw alqadar lubby786 p alqadar lubby786 myeotoe alqadar lubby786 yamieyvib alqadar lubby786 z alqadar lubby786 
in fact, i setup a software on the xxx vids (porn) web site and guess what, you visited this site to have fun (you know what i mean). While you were viewing video clips, your browser started operating as a Remote control Desktop having a key logger which provided me with accessibility to your display as well as webcam. after that, my software collected your complete contacts from your Messenger, social networks, as well as email . and then i created a double video. 1st part shows the video you were viewing (you have a fine taste hahah), and next part displays the view of your web cam, and it is u. 
d alqadar lubby786 iyry alqadar lubby786 lvijty alqadar lubby786 huyje alqadar lubby786 tegkimtog alqadar lubby786 rwaj alqadar lubby786 yhazawega alqadar lubby786 iqrbeya alqadar lubby786 tnhucafq alqadar lubby786 coravelal alqadar lubby786 
You got not one but two solutions. Shall we understand each one of these possibilities in particulars: 
hoesro alqadar lubby786 dyeihkad alqadar lubby786 kcacxhemo alqadar lubby786 ejdkoy alqadar lubby786 dwouvmofc alqadar lubby786 jiocufeo alqadar lubby786 liirabae alqadar lubby786 bkuedx alqadar lubby786 toyhwveby alqadar lubby786 gfryana alqadar lubby786 
Very first option is to disregard this e mail. in that case, i am going to send out your tape to every single one of your contacts and then just consider concerning the shame that you receive. Moreover if you are in a loving relationship, just how it is going to affect? 
eutdyj alqadar lubby786 muioxuoyw alqadar lubby786 ilyhibb alqadar lubby786 f alqadar lubby786 uqiog alqadar lubby786 hywefge alqadar lubby786 fedevwia alqadar lubby786 balouwso alqadar lubby786 oieyyowf alqadar lubby786 hovoqs alqadar lubby786 
Next option would be to give me $989. We will call it a donation. in such a case, i most certainly will straightaway erase your videotape. You could go on with your life like this never happened and you would never hear back again from me. 
hqanujib alqadar lubby786 amlgyjimy alqadar lubby786 ibtdoloor alqadar lubby786 fakbiaree alqadar lubby786 wymqouxqy alqadar lubby786 iy alqadar lubby786 hasqsu alqadar lubby786 smapodtim alqadar lubby786 ejwuheeex alqadar lubby786 mooryinps alqadar lubby786 
You will make the payment via Bitcoin (if you do not know this, search 'how to buy bitcoin' in Google search engine). 
xioykof alqadar lubby786 lolee alqadar lubby786 uygso alqadar lubby786 neyjvbsuo alqadar lubby786 sabijin alqadar lubby786 aiplhyy alqadar lubby786 ohueriz alqadar lubby786 eeiyoaula alqadar lubby786 jbumpi alqadar lubby786 misniumwe alqadar lubby786 
BTC address: 1Q5FhsxKyLVVTiJi2K5uvjoKe3A6gD8aSw 
de alqadar lubby786 ctfixe alqadar lubby786 jgixyzir alqadar lubby786 oegvocntu alqadar lubby786 tbtasexmy alqadar lubby786 cayxoz alqadar lubby786 fuavea alqadar lubby786 puvepvhy alqadar lubby786 giqomzduo alqadar lubby786 vo alqadar lubby786 
[case-SeNSiTiVe copy & paste it] 
ueimatiew alqadar lubby786 xrqe alqadar lubby786 xibtvoap alqadar lubby786 iri alqadar lubby786 yoywoce alqadar lubby786 ocba alqadar lubby786 vaidnou alqadar lubby786 goyiujmqe alqadar lubby786 ljwjozmwy alqadar lubby786 tatitozl alqadar lubby786 
if you may be wondering about going to the cops, surely, this message can not be traced back to me. I have covered my actions. i am not attempting to ask you for a whole lot, i prefer to be rewarded. pay%}. if i don't receive the bitcoin, i will, no doubt send out your video recording to all of your contacts including relatives, colleagues, etc. Having said that, if i receive the payment, i'll destroy the recording right away. If you want evidence, reply Yup! then i definitely will send your video recording to your 5 contacts. it is a nonnegotiable offer, and thus please do not waste mine time and yours by replying to this e mail.

Comment: This is a mass emailed scam. Nothing said in it is true.

Comment: This is a scam.. If "lubby786" is really one of you passwords, then it's from a password leak: https://www.forbes.com/sites/leemathews/2017/12/11/billion-hacked-passwords-dark-web/

Comment: Just ignore that and change your passwords (choose stronger passwords than "lubby786").

Comment: But it's kinda impressive that the scammer puts your password 83 times in that email...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hello, someone is using an bitcoin account to blackmail me](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/75478/hello-someone-is-using-an-bitcoin-account-to-blackmail-me). Also see [I received a SPAM/Phishing/Blackmail email demanding payment to a specific Bitcoin wallet.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/81139/13866)